# SQL - What is the best way to work for this SELECT CASE?

Tags: sql, select, case, grouping

I have a table Attendance and a table with Activity Types

I want to group per month the activities per persons in separate columns

Example table:

### Attendance

Person ID
Date
GateIn
GateOut
ActivityID

### Activity

ID
Name

Values are Activity.Name are: Present, Absence, Ill and Holiday

### I want to get a view like (Grouped per Person ID and month

PersonID
Month
Year
Absence
Holiday
Ill
LessThan4Hours
MoreThan4Hours
MoreThan5Hours

What is the best way to create this grouping??
I already have two SQL statements, but both seems to be too unfriendly

Who could help me out???
Thanks

```
    SELECT year(att.Date) as cYear, month(att.Date) as cMonth, att.PersonID, COUNT(1) as Absence, 0 as Holiday, 0 as Ill, 0 as LessThan4Hours, 0 as MoreThan4Hours, 0 as MoreThan5Hours
    FROM Attendance att
    inner join Activities act on att.ActivityID = act.ID
    WHERE act.Name = 'Absence'
    GROUP BY year(att.Date), month(att.Date), att.PersonID
    UNION
    SELECT year(att.Date) as cYear, month(att.Date) as cMonth, att.PersonID, 0 as Absence, COUNT(1) as Holiday, 0 as Ill, 0 as LessThan4Hours, 0 as MoreThan4Hours, 0 as MoreThan5Hours
    FROM Attendance att
    inner join Activities act on att.ActivityID = act.ID
    WHERE act.Name = 'Holiday'
    GROUP BY year(att.Date), month(att.Date), att.PersonID
    UNION
    SELECT year(att.Date) as cYear, month(att.Date) as cMonth, att.PersonID, 0 as Absence, 0 as Holiday, count(1) as Ill, 0 as LessThan4Hours, 0 as MoreThan4Hours, 0 as MoreThan5Hours
    FROM Attendance att
    inner join Activities act on att.ActivityID = act.ID
    WHERE act.Name = 'Ill'
    GROUP BY year(att.Date), month(att.Date), att.PersonID
    UNION
    SELECT year(att.Date) as cYear, month(att.Date) as cMonth, att.PersonID, 0 as Absence, 0 as Holiday, 0 as Ill, COUNT(1) as LessThan4Hours, 0 as MoreThan4Hours, 0 as MoreThan5Hours
    FROM Attendance att
    inner join Activities act on att.ActivityID = act.ID
    WHERE att.GateOut is not null
    AND (DATEDIFF(n, att.GateIn, att.GateOut)/60) <= 4
    AND act.Name = 'Present'
    GROUP BY year(att.Date), month(att.Date), att.PersonID
    UNION
    SELECT year(att.Date) as cYear, month(att.Date) as cMonth, att.PersonID, 0 as Absence, 0 as Holiday, 0 as Ill, 0 as LessThan4Hours, COUNT(1) as MoreThan4Hours, 0 as MoreThan5Hours
    FROM Attendance att
    inner join Activities act on att.ActivityID = act.ID
    WHERE att.GateOut is not null
    AND (DATEDIFF(n, att.GateIn, att.GateOut)/60) > 4
    AND (DATEDIFF(n, att.GateIn, att.GateOut)/60) <= 5
    AND act.Name = 'Present'
    GROUP BY year(att.Date), month(att.Date), att.PersonID
    UNION
    SELECT year(att.Date) as cYear, month(att.Date) as cMonth, att.PersonID, 0 as Absence, 0 as Holiday, 0 as Ill, 0 as LessThan4Hours, 0 as MoreThan4Hours, COUNT(1) as MoreThan5Hours
    FROM Attendance att
    inner join Activities act on att.ActivityID = act.ID
    WHERE att.GateOut is not null
    AND (DATEDIFF(n, att.GateIn, att.GateOut)/60) > 5
    AND act.Name = 'Present'
    GROUP BY year(att.Date), month(att.Date), att.PersonID
```

and i also worked this out in SELECT CASE, maybe even worse?

```
    SELECT a.PersonID, a.cYear, a.cMonth, SUM(a.Absence) AS Absence, SUM(a.Holiday) AS Holiday, SUM(a.Ill) AS Ill, SUM(a.LessThan4Hours) AS LessThan4Hours, SUM(a.MoreThan4Hours) AS MoreThan4Hours, SUM(a.MoreThan5Hours) AS MoreThan5Hours
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT year(att.Date) as cYear, month(att.Date) as cMonth, att.PersonID, CASE 
        WHEN act.Name = 'Ill' THEN 1
        WHEN act.Name = 'Holiday' THEN 0
        WHEN act.Name = 'Absence' THEN 0
        WHEN GateOut = null THEN 0
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) > 5 THEN 0
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) > 4 THEN 0
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) <= 4 THEN 0
        ELSE 0 
      END AS Ill,
       CASE 
        WHEN act.Name = 'Ill' THEN 0
        WHEN act.Name = 'Holiday' THEN 1
        WHEN act.Name = 'Absence' THEN 0
        WHEN GateOut = null THEN 0
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) > 5 THEN 0
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) > 4 THEN 0
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) <= 4 THEN 0
        ELSE 0 
      END AS Holiday,
      CASE 
        WHEN act.Name = 'Ill' THEN 0
        WHEN act.Name = 'Holiday' THEN 0
        WHEN act.Name = 'Absence' THEN 1
        WHEN GateOut = null THEN 0
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) > 5 THEN 0
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) > 4 THEN 0
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) <= 4 THEN 0
        ELSE 0 
      END AS Absence,
      CASE 
        WHEN act.Name = 'Ill' THEN 0
        WHEN act.Name = 'Holiday' THEN 0
        WHEN act.Name = 'Absence' THEN 0
        WHEN GateOut = null THEN 0
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) > 5 THEN 1
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) > 4 THEN 0
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) <= 4 THEN 0
        ELSE 0
      END AS MoreThan5Hours,
      CASE 
        WHEN act.Name = 'Ill' THEN 0
        WHEN act.Name = 'Holiday' THEN 0
        WHEN act.Name = 'Absence' THEN 0
        WHEN GateOut = null THEN 0
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) > 5 THEN 0
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) > 4 THEN 1
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) <= 4 THEN 0
        ELSE 0 
      END AS MoreThan4Hours,
      CASE 
        WHEN act.Name = 'Ill' THEN 0
        WHEN act.Name = 'Holiday' THEN 0
        WHEN act.Name = 'Absence' THEN 0
        WHEN GateOut = null THEN 0
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) > 5 THEN 0
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) > 4 THEN 0
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) <= 4 THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
      END AS LessThan4Hours
  from Attendance att
  inner join Activities act on att.ActivityID = act.ID 
  ) a
  GROUP BY a.PersonID, a.cYear, a.cMonth
  ORDER BY a.cYear DESC, a.cMonth DESC, a.PersonID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be much easier to read and follow.  The inner "PreChk" query goes through the records and just flags them as their different type and hours, then applies a summarization grouped by your requirements.

```
SELECT
      PreChk.PersonID, 
      PreChk.cYear, 
      PreChk.cMonth,
      SUM(PreChk.Absence) AS Absence, 
      SUM(PreChk.Holiday) AS Holiday, 
      SUM(PreChk.Ill) AS Ill, 
      SUM( case when PreChk.HrsDif > 5 then 1 else 0 end ) as MoreThan5Hours,
      SUM( case when PreChk.HrsDif > 4 AND PreChk.HrsDif < 5 then 1 else 0 end ) as MoreThan4Hours,
      SUM( case when PreChk.HrsDif < 4 then 1 else 0 end ) as LessThan4Hours
   from 
      ( SELECT 
              att.PersonID, 
              year(att.Date) as cYear, 
              month(att.Date) as cMonth, 
              CASE WHEN act.Name = 'Ill' THEN 1 else 0 end as Ill,
              CASE WHEN act.Name = 'Holiday' THEN 1 else 0 end as Holiday,
              CASE WHEN act.Name = 'Absence' THEN 1 else 0 end as Absence,
              CASE when GateOut = null 
                   THEN 0
                   ELSE DATEDIFF(n, gatein, gateout)/60) end as HrsDif
           from 
              Attendance att
                 inner join Activities act 
                    on att.ActivityID = act.ID ) PreChk
   GROUP BY 
      PreChk.PersonID, 
      PreChk.cYear, 
      PreChk.cMonth
   ORDER BY 
      PreChk.cYear DESC, 
      PreChk.cMonth DESC, 
      PreChk.PersonID
```

Comment: I did not knew that you could CASE as a different column name! How great !

Comment: @Cedric, click on the help / tour option for etiquette and marking of questions.  This helps others to know when questions are "solved" so others don't waste time trying to try solving something already done, and helps others to know what DID work if they encounter similar problems in their work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8ef9/1) showing this method

```
select personid, 
         datepart(month, date) as Month, 
         datepart(year, date) as year, 
         case when [present] is not null then 1 else 0 end as present,
         case when [absence] is not null then 1 else 0 end as absence,
         case when [III] is not null then 1 else 0 end as III,
         case when [holiday] is not null then 1 else 0 end as holiday,
         sum(case when datediff(hour, gatein, gateout) <= 4 then 1 else 0 end) as LessThan4Hours,
         sum(case when datediff(hour, gatein, gateout) > 4 and datediff(hour, gatein, gateout) <= 5 then 1 else 0 end) as GreaterThan4Hours,
         sum(case when datediff(hour, gatein, gateout) > 5 then 1 else 0 end) as GreaterThan5Hours
  from 
  (
    select a.*, act.name
    from attendance a
    join activity act on a.activityid = act.activityid
  ) as source
  pivot
  (
    max(name)
    FOR name in ([present],[absence],[III],[holiday])
  ) as p
  group by personid, 
           datepart(month, date), 
           datepart(year, date), 
           case when [present] is not null then 1 else 0 end,
           case when [absence] is not null then 1 else 0 end,
           case when [III] is not null then 1 else 0 end,
           case when [holiday] is not null then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: interesting, but is not exactly returning the same results that i expected.. But this encourage me to learn more about pivoting in sql. thanks anyway